# Grails services: can these be configured to run on a scheduled basis?

Tags: grails, service

I am admittedly new to grails, and I am finding it very interesting.

What I want to know is if a Grails service can be called/run in a sort of "headless" mode, untied to any GSP, and further, executed on a scheduled basis?

Thanks,
Alexx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Quartz plugin for scheduled jobs: http://grails.org/plugin/quartz